# When is "overqualified" an issue when applying?

Tags: job-change, health

Will an employer look suspiciously at a resume with more technical experience than the job requires? For example, if one wants to move from a software job to more of a secretary's job?

Brief background: I currently have an IT job but due to cancer-related health issues require something with more regular hours and straightforward tasks.

Should a resume be "watered down" so that it does not look as technical? My fear is that it will seem as if I was fired for something like behavioral issues when the truth is I needed to leave due to cancer.

Comment: I think in your particular health case, you should probably include that in your cover letter. Explaining why you would love to be in a lower position due to your cancer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The related question explains why companies may not want to hire overqualified people.  So in your cover letter, you need to explain why you're a good choice anyway.  Tell why you are interested in that job, and you won't plan on immediately leaving.

You may not want to mention medical specifics like cancer.  But you could say something about how you have a medical condition that requires a lower level of work that you have been doing, and then explain why this particular job looks like something you can excel in and be happy with.  You might want to go ahead and speak about money too, in that you don't expect that this job will pay as well, and explain why that is acceptable.

You need to assure them right off that you're not trying to get your foot in the door so you can immediately move up, that you're not just taking a job and will leave as soon as a more suitable job comes up.  It needs to be clear in your cover letter that this is a job you think will be suitable, and why you aren't a flight risk.